# Why do asynchronous calls in C# need to be declared as such if the method they reside in is declared with the 'async' keyword already?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, architecture

Now, there's a 99% chance that this "nitpick" I have found is entirely due to my own ignorance - I'm a junior web developer who has only been exposed to C# sporadically for a couple of months, so I apologize in advance for the probable stupidity of my question. Most of my experience is with PHP and JS.

If I have a method declared with the `async` keyword as such:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(MyObject myObject)
    {
    }
```

Why do I also have to specify that LINQ statements be asynchronous explicitly like so:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(MyObject myObject)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            myObject.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            myObject.DisplayId = await db.MyObjects.MaxAsync(m => m.DisplayId) + 1;
            db.MyObjects.Add(myObject);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(myObject);
    }
```

Can't the C# compiler be clever enough to figure out that because the method is asynychronous, the LINQ statements I want to execute within the method should be asynchronous too?

I guess my real beef with this is that there's now an asynchronous twin for most LINQ methods (`SaveChangesAsync`, `MaxAsync`, `FirstOrDefaultAsync`), and I have to use the `await` keyword every time I want to execute such calls. It seems excessively verbose and unnecessary.

If granular control over the synchronicity of the call was still needed, why didn't the C# developers simply allow for an `.Await()`,`.Async()`, or `Sync()` method that I could append?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, and has nothing to do with ASP.Net.

Comment: @SLaks apologies. I'll try and improve it if I can. Your comment is rather unclear though. What specifically is unclear?

Comment: @SLaks I have removed the ASP.NET tag and reworded the title.

Comment: @EchoLogic Trying to understand.. is your complaint about need for having await in front of async method like db.MyObjects.MaxAsync?

Comment: @Yogiraj, essentially, yes. It just seems rather verbose. It's not so much a complaint, more I'm trying to understand the rationale behind the approach taken by the C# developers when they built out async/await into C# 5.

Comment: I pinged Eric Lippert on Twitter, I'm sure he'll have a good explanation ;)

Comment: @EchoLogic: You may be interested in [a blog post I wrote on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can't the C# compiler be clever enough to figure out that because the method is asynychronous, the LINQ statements I want to execute within the method should be asynchronous too?

What if you want to make a synchronous call in an asynchronous method?

Do you want the same method to be synchronous or asynchronous depending on whether or not you're in an asynchronous method? I guess it would be possible for a language to do that, but it would require a fundamentally different model that is not the one used by C#. Also, I'm not sure it would be a good idea; it could be pretty confusing. Better to make things explicit IMO.

> I guess my real beef with this is that there's now an asynchronous twin for most LINQ methods (SaveChangesAsync, MaxAsync, FirstOrDefaultAsync), and I have to use the await keyword every time I want to execute such calls. It seems excessively verbose and unnecessary.

Using `await` or not doesn't have the same meaning. If you don't use `await`, you just retrieve the task, which can be useful in some scenarios (e.g. if you want to parallelize tasks. For instance, consider the following:

```
Task t1 = SomeAsyncOperation();
Task t2 = SomeOtherAsyncOperation();
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
```

In the code above, the operations run in parallel. Now, if you use await on each call:

```
await SomeAsyncOperation();
await SomeOtherAsyncOperation();
```

The operations are now sequential.

The developer *needs* to be in control of this kind of thing. That's why the `await` cannot be implicit, because it changes the behavior of the code.

> If granular control over the synchronicity of the call was still needed, why didn't the C# developers simply allow for an .Await() or .Async() method that I could append?

How would a `.Await()` method be better than a keyword? Anyway, it wouldn't work. The use of the `await` keyword transforms the body of the method into a state machine; a method call can't do that.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from, and guess this comes down more to preferred style, but I offered a solution to control in my question. Wouldn't it have been better to use 'Sync()' or 'Async()' methods that could be appended to calls rather than creating a whole bunch of Async twins for pre-existing synchronous methods?

Answer (score 1):

`await` completely changes the way code for the method is generated - state machine vs. linear code - so you can't magically implement it with any custom `.Await()` method because method calls compiled into linear code.

C# generally chooses explicit approach vs. magically guess intentions - so while there are cases when compiler may guess need for `await` call it does not.

Note that with `var` it frequently impossible to make a guess either:

```
var displayId = db.MyObjects.MaxAsync(m => m.DisplayId);
```

`displayId` could be `Task` or if compiler allowed to guess for missing `await` it could be `int`.